# Help with constructing a jordan form basis

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

My question is concerning Lemma 2.3 in the following paper , ["On the Irreducibility of Commuting Varieties
of Nilpotent Matrices
"](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0301215v1.pdf)

[image]

Specifically, I'm trying to understand the second half of the proof where Basili shows that we can construct a basis that will give us the desired upper triangular matrix. I'm not quite following their notation here. If somebody could explain this in more explicit terms than are used here that would be great.

Comment: Is it possible to summarize the problem without external link?

Comment: Is there a way to post an image on this site? The chunk I'm referring to is only about a paragraph long, but the notation looks hard to type out.

Comment: @Damon got you covered